# (Java Swing) Having a problem with layouts

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I am fairly new to java and programming overall. I've read quite an amount of information and watched a lot of videos about layouts, but even then upon my first try to make a program my screen goes all empty.
I am trying to make two panels for different usage and I am trying to add components to the sides (Left: one north panel will be used for buttons, Right: north, east and south panels will be used for buttons).
Here is the code:

```
public class SNGUI {
public JFrame f = new JFrame();

JPanel panelright = new JPanel(); //contains UT/LWmenu/MetaMenu
JPanel panelleft = new JPanel(); //contains TextArea document / TextEditors
JPanel TextEditorsPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel UpperToolsPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel LowerToolsPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel SettingsPanel = new JPanel();

public SNGUI() {

    //Frame characteristics
    f.setTitle("Study Notes v 0.00.0");
    f.setSize(1440,900);
    f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    f.setResizable(true);
    f.setVisible(true);

    // Main panel layouts
    panelright.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panelleft.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // Additional panel layouts
    //TextEditors.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING,0,0));

    // Lower Tools Buttons
    LTButtons[0] = new JButton("Calculator");

    // colors (delete later)
    panelleft.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    panelright.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    TextEditorsPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    UpperToolsPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    LowerToolsPanel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    SettingsPanel.setBackground(Color.pink);

    //panelright.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,100));


    panelleft.add(TextEditorsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panelright.add(UpperToolsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panelright.add(LowerToolsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panelright.add(SettingsPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    f.add(panelleft);
    f.add(panelright);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SNGUI StudyNotes = new SNGUI();
}
```

}

Comment: The issue here is that you call `f.setVisible(true)` before you actually add any components to your `JFrame`. This should be called when all the components are added, as this will trigger the logic to paint all components that are contained in your frame. So, to fix your issue, move it down to be the last line of your constructor.

Comment: Sidenote, you should get used to the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) to make your code more readable for others. In your example, your `JPanel`s variable names should start lowercase.

Comment: *I've read quite an amount of information* - start with the working examples found in the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Download the working demo code and make changes. The demo code will also show you how to better structure your code so that the GUI is created on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). All Swing components should be created and updated on the EDT. Keep a reference to the tutorial handy for all Swing basics.

Comment: Your code should not be using setSize(). You should be using pack() and setVisible(true) AFTER adding the components.  By default all components have a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.  So you need to make sure the layout manager is invoked AFTER all components are added to the frame.

Comment: You changed the layoutManager for the JFrame to a GridLayout, and NORTH and EAST doesn't work on a GridLayout.

Comment: @NomadMaker the BorderLayout constraints are applied to "panelLeft" and "panelRight" which do use a BorderLayout.